# Does numpy.einsum act differently on arrays loaded by cv2?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy-einsum

The [example in numpy's documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) of `einsum` says `np.einsum('ij->i', a)` functions similar to `np.sum(a, axis=1)`. Below, example 1 confirms this while example 2 contradicts it. Any idea what I am doing (expecting) wrong?

Exp 1.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
b1 = np.einsum('ij->i', a)   # array([ 10,  35,  60,  85, 110])
b2 = np.sum(a, axis=1)       # array([ 10,  35,  60,  85, 110])
```

Exp 2.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

img_path = "path/to/an/image.png"
im = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)    # type: numpy.ndarray
n1 = np.einsum('ij->i', im)
n2 = np.sum(img, axis=1)
# to show that they are different.
print(np.max(n1), np.max(n2))  # out: 255 119630
```

Why `n1` and `n2` are not identical (as their `max` values indicate)?

Comment: As written, no one can reproduce this, without knowing `img_path`.  In fact, it looks like you have a typo in your second code block: `im`/`img`.  It would be great if you could provide a smaller, reproducible example of this effect in the body of your question.  Even just printing the shape of `img` would be informative.

Comment: @NicholasM, thanks. I made some changes. It is reproducible; the user however, needs an image in their local machine. The shape depends on the loaded image. If it helps, mine was a 512X512 image that turned into a 2d matrix of the same shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images loaded with cv2 (and PIL) will be of type `uint8`. Computations within a type may not have the same result compared to others.

```
>>> np.uint8(255) + np.uint8(1)
0
>>> np.int32(255) + np.int32(1)
256
```

`np.arange` by default creates an array of type `int32`, so there are no issues. But

```
a = np.arange(64, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(8, 8)
b1 = np.einsum('ij->i', a)
b2 = np.sum(a, axis=1)
print(b1 == b2)
```

prints

```
[ True  True  True  True False False False False]
```

Note that `np.sum` converts the type under the hood so it can accommodate additions not limited by a shorter type. That isn't to say `uint32` won't have problems if it has to deal with values outside its supported range, but it's less likely.

```
>>> np.sum(np.uint8([1, 2])).dtype
dtype('uint32')
```

Just make sure you use a data type that won't run into any issues for your specific problem.

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.uint32)  # or np.int32
print(np.all(n1 == n2))   # this should now be true
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your detailed answer.